# Template for a single dimension array with Knockout.js and ko.mapping

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a JSON string that I am mapping with ko.mapping plugin and I need to create observable bindings for one of the mapped arrays. The array is in the JSON as [1,2,3,4,5] so it has no index.

I have the following code working to a certain point:

```
<script id="statRowTemplate" type="text/html">
    {{if type() != "column"}}
    <tr>
            <td><label>Name: </label><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><label>Plot Points: </label><ul data-bind="template: {name: 'dataTemplate' , foreach: data}"></ul> </td>
    </tr>
    {{/if}}
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="dataTemplate">         
<li>
    <p>${this.data}</p>
        <input data-bind="value: this.data" />
</li>
</script>
<button data-bind="click: saveChanges">Save Changes</button>
```

So everything is working as expected except `<input data-bind="value: this.data" />` That field remains blank ... `${this.data}` Shows the correct value however.

Overall, I am tying to update a JSON string and re-save it in a flat file. I can bind the data array: `[1,2,3,4]` directly to the input value but then it does not update as an array.

Here is the viewModel:
        var viewModel = {};

```
$.getJSON('/data-forecast-accuracy.json', function(result) {

    viewModel.stats = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
    console.log(result)
    viewModel.saveChanges = function() {

        var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel.stats);
        console.log(unmapped);

        $.post('save-changes.php', {data: unmapped})
        .success(function() { console.log("second success"); })
        .error(function() {  console.log("error"); })
        .complete(function() {  console.log("complete"); });
    }

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Here is the JSON:

`[
  {
    "type":"spline",
    "marker":{
      "symbol":"diamond"
    },
    "name":"Cumulative",
    "data":[10,17,18,18,16,17,18,19]
  },
  {
    "type":"spline",
    "marker":{
      "symbol":"circle"
    },
    "name":"Monthly",
    "data":[10,22,20,19,8,20,25,23]
  }
]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also open to suggestions if I am approaching this from the wrong angle. Ultimately just want to be able to modify the JSON sting through a UI and then save it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly edit a value in the array, you will want to map the original array to a structure that contains an actual property to bind against `[1,2,3]` becomes `[{val: 1}, {val: 2}, {val: 3}]`.  Binding against `$data` will not work, as KO is not able to determine how to update it from user input (currently not able to understand that it is located at some index in an array).

I like to do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/vv2Wx/

This uses [this](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html) technique to make the array look like the original automatically when it is turned into JSON.

Comment: Perfect. You will have to forgive my ignorance as I am very new to knockout.js - I think part of my trouble is understanding how the ko.mapping array works. So when I am trying to get to that data and map it as you suggested, would I need to map that for each iteration in the template?

Comment: Okay. After a bit of fiddling I got this to work. Just used the create mapping options to return the Item directly. Thank you so much!