# KnockoutJS - force number for specific field using ko.mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

When I use `ko.mapping.toJSON` it converts any changes I made into strings and they need to be numbers. I tried using the custom mapping like so:

```
    var mapping = {
   'y': {
        update: function(options) {
                return parseFloat(options.data);
        }
    }
}
```

... but this only keeps them as numbers inside the contect of the page. Since I am using this to update and external JSON that gets pulled in by HighCharts.js the numbers need to stay numbers even after the toJSON.

From an earlier answer here I was able to use:

```
//override toJSON to turn it back into a single val
    mappedData.prototype.toJSON = function() {
       return parseInt(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.val), 10);  //parseInt if you want or not 
    };
```

... which worked swimmingly. However this is just a single value type in the JSON so I am unclear on how I could use the same override for it. Do I need to create a whole new object to do this in this instance as well. Or is their something more concise?

Comment: Well. I just used the same functionality as in this post. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612046/template-for-a-single-dimension-array-with-knockout-js-and-ko-mapping

Similar but I am still interested to know if this is the "best" way to go about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you edit a value in an input, the value will end up being a string.  Knockout reads the new value from the element and it is always a string.

If you want to keep it numeric, look at the answer on this question: [Knockout.js: time input format and value restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395946/knockout-js-json-has-numeric-but-knockout-changes-it-to-string-any-suggestions) for a couple of ways to do it.  If you use the custom binding (`numericValue`) in the answer, then you do not need to do anything else with the mapping options.  If you use the `numericObservable` idea, then you would need to use the mapping options to ensure that it was creating these special observable rather than just a normal observable.

Otherwise, you can continue to use the `toJSON` override as well.